# Python if problem with analyzing numbers if number before is positive or negative?

Tags: python, if-statement

so my goal is to make program that scans numbers and if number before zero is negative and number after zero is positive it prints "Zero is positive" and if opposite "Zero is negative". Problem is that every time i enter numbers it always prints only "Zero is negative" for now program should only work with 1 zero and 2 numbers but i will later expend. Here is my code:

```
number = input("Enter Numbers: ")
lists = []
lists = number.split()
print(lists)
z = 0
y = 0
x = 0
indexes = [index for index, element in enumerate(lists) if element == "0"]
print(indexes)

pos = indexes[0] - 1
neg = indexes[0] + 1
zero = indexes[0]

if(int(neg) < zero and zero > int(pos)):
   print("Zero is postive")
else:
   print("Zero is negative")
```

Comment: The elements of `indexes` is a monotonically increasing set of indices, not values from the list. It will always be true that `index[0] - 1 < index[0] < index[0] + 1`, but you require `index[0] > index[0] + 1` be true to print "positive".

Comment: Please provide sample test case in order to help people easily understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the problem statement correctly, you need to compare the list elements at the indexes but are comparing the indexes. So the condition in `if` should be changed from:

```py
if(int(neg) < zero and zero > int(pos)):
```

to something like this (note that you don't need braces in python's `if`):

```py
if list[neg] > list[zero] > list[pos]:
```

Answer (score 0):

As already been told, you should compare the values in the list not the index numbers.

Also, there is a logical error in this statement `if(int(neg) < zero and zero > int(pos)):`, it actually checks if both `neg` and `both` are less that `zero`.

And perhaps is more clear if `neg` points the previous to `zero` value and `pos` the next one.

I modified a bit your code and I think it works correctly:

```
number = input("Enter Numbers: ")
lists = []
lists = number.split()
print(lists)
z = 0
y = 0
x = 0
indexes = [index for index, element in enumerate(lists) if element == "0"]
print(indexes)

neg = int(indexes[0] - 1)
pos = int(indexes[0] + 1)
zero = int(indexes[0])

if lists[neg] < lists[zero] < lists[pos]:
    print("Zero is postive")
else:
   print("Zero is negative")
```